# How to fix Google DataFlow Pipeline (args) null pointer exception?

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to run a really simple dataflow job, just taking some data in BigQuery, processing it a bit and putting it in a new bigquery table

`Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(
                PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create());
p.apply(BigQueryIO.Read.fromQuery("SELECT * FROM realtime.status_6_output_11"));
        p.run();`

However whenever I run it I get the following pretty undescriptive NullPointerException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1283)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:309)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:229)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1093)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.IOChannelUtils.getFactory(IOChannelUtils.java:174)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.BigQueryIO$Read$Bound.apply(BigQueryIO.java:553)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.BigQueryIO$Read$Bound.apply(BigQueryIO.java:387)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.PipelineRunner.apply(PipelineRunner.java:74)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner.apply(DirectPipelineRunner.java:247)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:367)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:274)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.PBegin.apply(PBegin.java:47)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.apply(Pipeline.java:156)
    at com.noraway.conductor.NormalizedPipeline.main(NormalizedPipeline.java:42)

I think there's a problem with my command line arguments (don't have any right now) but I'm not sure what that would be.
```

Comment: Guessing: **args** is null?!

Comment: Don't think that's it

Comment: How do you run it? Do you pass arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a missing --tempLocation for BigQuery to use.  The obscure error message is fixed as part of https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/issues/313.